# How to detect a network connection in mobile browser?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, browser

There is [Network information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection) which is currently supported only on latest [Android devices](http://caniuse.com/#search=network).

What are the existing workarounds if any to get such information (2G, 3G) on iOS devices?

Comment: iOS does not expose this information to the browser.

Comment: You can find out if the user has a connection by sending an ajax request to some blank page somewhere, if the http code is OK, then the user has internet